# Creating a map from an array of struct pointers

Tags: pointers, dictionary, struct, go

I have an array of pointers to structs. The structs have a `name` field. I want to create a map from names to pointers to structs.

Why are all of the values in the `registry` map identical?

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Thing struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}

type Registry map[string]*Thing

func toRegistry(things *[]Thing) Registry {

    registry := make(Registry)

    for _, thing := range *things {
        registry[thing.Name] = &thing
    }
    return registry
}

func main() {

    things := []Thing{{"thingA", 1}, {"thingB", 2}}
    registry := toRegistry(&things)
    fmt.Println(registry)

}
```

Sample output: `map[thingB:0x10436180 thingA:0x10436180]`

[GO](https://play.golang.org/p/OJ0_Tfxtsf)

### EDIT

Per @tvblah's suggestion, `things` was already a slice, so there's no need to point to it:

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Thing struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}

type Registry map[string]*Thing

func toRegistry(things []Thing) Registry {

    registry := make(Registry)

    for _, thing := range things {
        registry[thing.Name] = &thing
    }
    return registry
}

func main() {

    things := []Thing{{"thingA", 1}, {"thingB", 2}}
    registry := toRegistry(things)
    fmt.Println(registry)
```

[GO](https://play.golang.org/p/tbZt6WWyEd)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each map value is a pointer to the single local variable `thing`.

One fix is to add an pointer to the slice element:

```
func toRegistry(things []Thing) Registry {

  registry := make(Registry)

  for i := range things {
    registry[things[i].Name] = &things[i]
  }
  return registry
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/kBBEOXMgu5)

Another option is to store pointers to `Thing` in the slice:

```
func toRegistry(things []*Thing) Registry {
  registry := make(Registry)
  for _, thing := range things {
    registry[thing.Name] = thing
  }
  return registry
}

func main() {
  things := []*Thing{&Thing{"thingA", 1}, &Thing{"thingB", 2}}
  registry := toRegistry(things)
  fmt.Println(registry)
}
```

[playground](https://play.golang.org/p/ovwC-F-997)

I changed the function argument from a pointer to a slice to a slice. This change has no impact on the issue raised on the question, but it's generally how Go code is written. Pointers to slices are rarely used in Go.

Comment: This is the right answer. The behavior is very subtle, so if it's not clear in the original example `&thing` returns the address of the local variable in the loop. The spec says 
"their scope is the block of the "for" statement; they are re-used in each iteration."
So since `thing` is the same variable each time the address ends up being the same as well.

Answer (score 2):

You may reassign `thing` to another local variable on each iteration and store new variable in registry.

```
package main

import "fmt"

type Thing struct {
    Name  string
    Value int
}

type Registry map[string]*Thing

func toRegistry(things *[]Thing) Registry {

    registry := make(Registry)

    for _, thing := range *things {
        t := thing
        registry[thing.Name] = &t
    }
    return registry
}

func main() {

    things := []Thing{{"thingA", 1}, {"thingB", 2}}
    registry := toRegistry(&things)
    fmt.Println(registry)

}
```

[Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/cX9svslZjW)

Comment: would @tvblah's solution be more efficient?

Comment: @mheiber The three solutions are logically different.  This one stores a pointer to a newly allocated `Thing`.  The first of my solutions stores a pointer to the slice element.  The second of my solutions stores whatever the pointer is in the slice.  The logic in your application may dictate the choice.  This solution allocates a `Thing` on each iteration through the loop. My solutions do not.  The extra allocation will have a negligible impact on performance.

Comment: @mheiber, my solution is a bit less efficient due to allocation of new variable.